# What graph should represent a dataset with 2 variables?

Tags: python, matlab, graph, charts

say I have the following data:

```
CAR_TYPE, #rentals, AMOUNT
CLASS_1    350      $0.7M
CLASS_2    220      $1.3M
CLASS_3     55      $0.4M
```

What graph would you use in order present this data? One option would be a pie-chart but as you can see from the data, the charts would be totally different --depends on the emphasis:  numer of rentals or Amount.

Q: In general, having 2 variables for one TYPE what should be the preferred graph.

*I'm trying to achieve this in matlab (or python) but the concept is more important now then the actual implementation.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 2 variables (x, y) associated with each type (point) I would use a scatter plot. I would prefer a scatter plot if there are a lot of points (say 100). So the x-axis could represent #rentals, the y-axis could represent AMOUNT, and the intersections could represent the car types.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bar/column chart that looks like this:

http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Adobe_Flex_ColumnChart.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **3D bar** plot as presented in [this exemple of **matplotlib**](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#bar-plots) in python!